# Помогите заинжектить EntityManager в OSGi

Tags: java, entity

Пытаюсь создать новый модуль в проекте "по феншую" в работающей системе

- karaf
- felix
- OSGi

Конкретно хочу реализовать DAO слой с использованием JPA. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что в  OSGi все очень ущербно реализовано.

Конкретно я хочу получить в свой класc `EntityManager`

В спринге это все настолько просто

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "access")
    EntityManager entityManager;
```

и все. Но тут Документация говорит тоже так можно и на  stackoverflow  мне ответил разработчик этой системы что это можно [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789048/how-get-entitymanager-in-osgi-in-abstract-classlike-spring-persistencecontext)

Но ничего не работает.

В кратце он посоветовал прописать две строки в контекст

```
<jpa:enable/>
    <tx:enable-annotations/>
```

и все должно чудом заработать. но нет.
в том вопросе я уже описал проблему и возьму приложу код от туда сюда, может кто-то из наших поможет.

это конфигурация pastie.org/10747510 это мои классы pastie.org/10747507

П.С я могу использовать реализацию которая приводится в некоторых примерах. то есть в каждом DAO получать `EntityManager` прописывая для каждого дао бины в конфигах, и потом сетить `EntityManager` в эти дао и работать с `EntityManager` напрямую. Но это кал, и я хочу сделать один базовый ДАО в котором заинжектить `EntityManager` и реализовать методы, которые доступны наследникам, которые и будут DAO, которые мне нужны. То есть создать `EntityManager` один раз, и использовать везде, не передавая его в другие DAO.